# How can I define time limit to a user's group per session

Tags: limit, ulimit

I have the group ABC and I need to configure a time-limit to 2min per session for its members.

Like a TMOUT is only for a user, but I need for a group).

How can I define time limit to a user's group per session? 
(In /etc/security/limits.conf appear only cputime but it's different)